# Is "Paginator" part of the English lexicon?

Tags: vocabulary

I have searched in oxford dictionary online and I didn't find `Paginator` word there, I only found `Pagination` word and I can find `Googling` there.

So my questions are:

1. What should we call a something* that manage pagination?
2. Is it possible to use it in formal letter?

(*) Let say a script file that manage or generate pagination for a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English is a very flexible language, particularly with respect to technical language of this type.  If you were discussing a utility for pagination you would generally call it a "pagination utility" or script, but if it is a phrase that is going to come up often, using the word "paginator" would be understood by any audience who understands what pagination is.

I can find it being used in some instances to mean exactly what you suggest, an automated system for paginating.  Most are using it as part of a name in a programming environment (ex: paginatorFunction) but [here is an instance](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Paginator.html) of it being used in exactly the sense that you wish to use it.

Comment: doctrine use `Paginator` too to call their paginator class and `Phpstorm` considere `Paginator` as typo.  I just curious because I can find `Googling` in oxford dictionaries but I can't find `Paginator` there. so is it possible to use this word in formal letter?

Comment: If I were simply talking or sending emails to a technical person, I might use paginator, but in a formal setting, pagination utility or pagination script would be safer.